# bluemix DataCache sync to DB2

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

I'm using BlueMix's DataCache service infront of DB2 service.

Is there any way I can sync the cache to DB2 service easily?

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned that you have Bluemix DataCache in front of DB2 service, so I assume that you are trying with the inline cache use case - which is having your app sending distributed cache to DataCache and have DataCache write behind to the DB2.

If this is the use case that you try to do, the DataCache service in Bluemix currently didn't support this inline (write behind) cache.

One way I can see working for you is to use a side cache pattern. Have your application check the cached data in Data Cache service. If no entries are in the distributed cache, get it from DB2 service and then put it into the cache service. When data is needed to be changed by the application, you invalidate the cached data from Data Cache service and then update DB2 entries from your application. This is a typical side cache pattern that Data Cache services are supporting.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, helps a lot.
With the side cache pattern, do I need to do all the get/invalid/update manually or this could be achieved with configurations?

Comment: By configuration, I mean to let JPA(or other libs) to handle all these mappings from cache object to DB table, monitor and  sync the changes between cache with DB.
If all these sync and mapping work needs to be done manual, this could be way to complicated.

Comment: The current datacache service would require you write some integration code from your client app rather than just having configure changes to enable the use case you mentioned, since the client cannot access the server side of the configuration in the data cache. One way you could do is to have JPA to load data from the database, and then store the objects into the data cache server, and then apply the side cache pattern to look up from caching server before getting it from the DB. So you do need to call Data Cache client APIs to put/get your object.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links may help to make Data Cache client API call, it is quite simple to do by the way.

1. Build Java Application with the IBM Data Cache service
   http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-datacache-app/
2. Build an Enterprise Application with both IBM Data Cache and Session Cache service
   https://g01acxwass069.ahe.pok.ibm.com/cms/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-cacheservices-app/index.html
3. Use the indexing feature of the IBM Bluemix DataCache service
   http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-indexing-datacache-app/index.html
4. More Examples
   https://hub.jazz.net/project/abchow/CachingSamples/overview
   https://hub.jazz.net/project/abchow/CachingSamples/overview
   https://hub.jazz.net/project/rvennam/CloudTrader/overview

Note: you can also get "Java Cache Web Boiletplate" from BlueMix console catalog page, and then download the code from "Start code" in your Dashboard. The example will show you how you can code with the side cache pattern.